# Faster way to check a range of cells in a pandas dataframe for being NaN than using for loops, math.isnan(), and df.iloc()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to quickly check each cell in a range of columns across all rows in a dataframe (in the code example all cells) to see if they are NaN before performing some operations using the value of the cell.

Currently I am using a combination of for loops, `math.isnan()`, and `df.iloc()` and it is prohibitively slow when the dataframe is large.

```
for y in range(dataframe.shape[1]):
    for x in range(dataframe.shape[0]):
        if not math.isnan(dataframe.iloc[x][y]): 
            #do something using the value dataframe.iloc[x][y]
```

The code works, just slowly. In larger dataframes, thousands by thousands, it takes hours. Is there a faster/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: That's not how you use pandas. The two outer loops are unnecessary. The rest of the program depends on "_do something_". It will help if you tell what "_do something_" is.

Comment: pandas, being based on numpy, has implicit vectorisation in most of its functions so you should rarely if ever iterate over a dataframe.

Comment: The 'do something' does float math using the value of the cell, along with another, so it cannot be NaN. It then stores the value in a two dimensional list (i.e., Y columns x number of rows) that are later added to the dataframe as a Y new columns. I do not iterate over the entire dataframe but instead just a range of columns, i.e., columns 5-10.

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not know what exactly is done to the non-NaN elements, here's an illustration of how they can be inverted:

```
dataframe[dataframe.notna()] = 1 / dataframe
```

As you can see, there are no loops involved. If you need a more specific answer, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I am trying to do is for each row divide the value in some column X by the value in some column Y then add these values as a new column named Q. I am doing this across a range of columns, i.e., X to Z, and adding a new column for each, hence the loops. My columns are multi-indexed, such as ('a','two') ('a','one') and I could not figure out how to get .apply() to work in such a case so I went back to how I would have done it in Java years ago. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So, please update your question. Add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to it that reflects your comment. The example that you currently have is neither complete nor verifiable.